# `require': cannot load such file -- rails/all (LoadError)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, ruby-on-rails-plugins

I got the below error while running rspec for plugin.

cannot load such file -- rails/all (LoadError)

> require 'rails/all' defined in application.rb

Can anybody assist me how to solve the above issue?

Comment: How do you run the command ? Do you use bundle ?

Comment: Is the spec for a Rails app or gem?

Comment: Hi Geoffroy, I used rspec spec command.

Comment: Hi Rich,Spec for plugins

Comment: So the actual commands that you type into the terminal are... `rspec` or `rake spec` or `rspec spec` ?

Comment: Hi Taryn,I typed rspec spec

Comment: I got rid of this error after adding rails to the gemspec.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like rspec can't find the rails gem, which usually means the gem is not installed globally. Try using:

```
bundle exec rspec spec
```

This will load all of your Gemfile's gems into rspec's environment to allow them to be loaded.